# Do i need to use MX records to send a message from my own client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, smtp

If i want to host my own SMTP server and send messages from it, do i need to make a connection (net.createConnection or tls.connect) **to MX Record on port 25**, right? (for example gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com: 25). As I understand connection like smtp.gmail.com: 587 needed to send a message from my gmail account, right?

Comment: Unclear. If you only want to send messages, a MX record for *your* host is not necessary. But if your host does not respond correctly, e.g. Wrong or untestable HELO name, possible that your opposite denies the mail. Do you want to write your own SMTP server?

Comment: I asked the question incorrectly, if I want to send mail from my own smtp server, do I need to connect to the MX record? (like this: gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com:25). If I understood everything correctly, then the MX record is needed in order to exchange mail between different services (for example, from Google to Outlook, or from my server to Google). But if I wanted to send a message inside the Google service, then I could connect to smtp.gmail.com, enter my username and password and send a message, do I understand the concept correctly?

Comment: Yes. The MX record type indicates that this is a E-Mail server. BUT: It does not indicate what "services" the Mail server provides, like: smtp, imap, pop3. Also you have to "guess" what port and/or TLS/SSL is supported.